# select com datetime mssql

Tags: php, laravel

To tentando fazer um select no ms sql porém não consigo usar datetime.

```
$dataInicio = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $input['data_inicio'])->format('Y-m-d');

$result = \DB::select('Select * from PESAGEM where cast(databruto as date) = ? and ativo = 1')  ,[$dataInicio]);
```

Tentei fazer por querybuilder e não consegui também, exemplo se eu usar essa consulta direto no banco eu obtenho retorno.

```
select * from pesagem where cast(datatara as date) = '2015-09-03' and ativo = 1
```

Como faria uma consulta usando formato de `datatime`?

Comment: Como assim não consegue usar datetime? tente explicar melhor a sua pegunta.

Comment: Bom, não sei qual o problema mas o php não me retorna nada quando faço a consulta, a mesma consulta que faço direto no banco porém la passo a data entre aspas

Comment: Tem gerado algum erro? Se está passando aspas no banco tenta assim no php 'Select * from PESAGEM where cast(databruto as date) = ''?'' and ativo = 1'

Comment: nao gera error, tras a variavel vazia, com aspas apresenta erro na variavel result

Comment: Qual o tipo da coluna? datetime? smalldate?

Comment: Está como datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   Pesagem
WHERE 
   CONVERT(DATETIME, databruto, 103) = '01/10/2015' AND Ativo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipular data com mysql seria

```
select datatara as date from pesagem where DATE(datatara) = '2015-09-03' and ativo = 1
```

ou

```
select datatara as date from pesagem where DATE_FORMAT(datatara, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-09-03' and ativo = 1
```